# Where is /cow for Linux booted from LiveUSB?

Tags: live-usb, initramfs, livecd, initrd, overlayfs

I wanted to see what files are added on top of ISO 9660 when LiveUSB Linux is running. When booted with `persistence` `upper` and `work` folders are on USB drive clearly seen. I run `mount` on Linux booted from LiveUSB "usual way" (w/out `persistence`) and saw `/` is mounted via `overlayfs` and `upperdir=/cow/upper`. But `sudo ls /cow` gives `no such file or directory`.

Where is `/cow` and how to see its contents?

Added 1:
I was able to extract contents of `initrd` from liveUSB via `unmkinitramfs` (see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/495524/446998)

```
$ find . -type f -exec bash -c 'cat {} | grep "/cow/upper" && ls -l {}' \;
    if [ ! -d /cow/upper ]; then
        mkdir -p /cow/upper
            /cow/lost+found|/cow/upper|/cow/log|/cow/crash|/cow/install-logs-*)     continue ;;
            mv "$cow_content" /cow/upper
    mount -t overlay -o "upperdir=/cow/upper,lowerdir=$mounts,workdir=/cow/work" "/cow" "$rootmnt" || panic "overlay mount failed"
-rw-r--r-- 1 alex alex 33834 Jun 24  2020 ./main/scripts/casper
```

Next step I envision is to understand how `/cow` is created because is not see in contents of `initrd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// Experience based on kubuntu 22 lts livecd

### after chroot

the last step of ramdisk (/cdrom/casper/initrd) is
`run-init {rootmnt}" "${init}" "$@"`

which do something like
`chroot {rootmnt}" "${init}" "$@"`

after that step it may affect the observation of the original mount point.

### before chroot

Fortunately there are ways to pause at an interactive shell before chrooting (press ctrl+d or exit to continue)

kernel boot cmdline args
`break=top,premount,mount,mountroot,bottom,init`
may do the trick.

//BTW: `manjaro 22` only support `break=premount` (same as `break=y`)
or `break=postmount`, not support multiple values compound with `,`

also another cmdline args might help
`debug` or `debug=y`
which turn on detail log during ramdisk running

// boot args can be edit at grub menu by press `e`
// those information comes from reading the ramdisk script

### in ramdisk

you already `unmkinitramfs` and found
`scripts/casper`
which handle casper-rw persistence things

./scripts/casper

```bash
setup_overlay() {
    image_directory="$1"
    rootmnt="$2"

    # Mount up the writable layer, if it is persistent then it may well
    # tell us what format we should be using.
    mkdir -p /cow
    cowdevice="tmpfs"
    cow_fstype="tmpfs"
    cow_mountopt="rw,noatime,mode=755"

    # Looking for "$(root_persistence_label)" device or file
    if [ -n "${PERSISTENT}" ]; then
        cowprobe=$(find_cow_device "$(root_persistence_label)")
        if [ -b "${cowprobe}" ]; then
            cowdevice=${cowprobe}
            cow_fstype=$(get_fstype "${cowprobe}")
            cow_mountopt="rw,noatime"
        else
            [ "$quiet" != "y" ] && log_warning_msg "Unable to find the persistent medium"
        fi
    fi

    mount -t ${cow_fstype} -o ${cow_mountopt} ${cowdevice} /cow || panic "Can not mount $cowdevice on /cow"
```

code here determine the persistence partition, and mount it

### keep /cow after chroot

in ramdisk shell, after /cow /root ready

```bash
mkdir /root/_cow
mount -o bind /cow /root/_cow
```

then after chroot into system, /_cow can access the original outer /cow

Comment: Thanks! I've discovered solution with `-bind` myself before reading your answer, I've posted an answer with `sed` command to edit casper script. As for pausing with kernel parameters, this is an interesting thought. BTW, please read my answer and comment why original mounts for `showmounts` result in empty folders, if you know. TIA

Comment: Yes, On-site investigation is simple and effective

Comment: @Martian2020 I didn't understand exactly the situation you described, the variable and part of script. Maybe you can explicitly point out which path should not be empty before you replace `move` by `bind`

Answer (score 1):

LiveUSB sticks use an overlay file system such as [overlayfs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OverlayFS).  There are a couple of different ones so I'm not certain which it uses but the principle is pretty much the same in each.

The root file system that you see is composed of layers.  For a LiveUSB this will be

- an upper writable layer
- a read-only lower layer containing your operating system image and often stored in a squashfs file.

Initially you see just the files in the lower layer because the upper (writable) layer is empty.  When you write new files they will be written to the upper layer.  But other changes such as moving a file and editing a file will actually cause the file to be copied to the upper layer from the lower layer.

The upper layer can be a few things.  If the LiveUSB doesn't have persistence it's often a tempfs stored only in RAM.  However if there's persistence it may be something different... perhaps it's a writable file formatted with EXT4.

If it's a writable file then you may be able to find that file and mount it separate to the overlayfs to poke around what's inside.

---

> Where is /cow and how to see its contents?

That's the most tricky part of this question to answer.  The fact is it may not exactly exist anymore, at least not under that name.

It did exist during the execution of initramfs.  But then initramfs called [pivot_root](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pivot_root.2.html) which would have moved it... and then most likely tried to unmount it so now no userland process can actually see it any more.  The Kernel must logically still have it mounted though.

If it was mounted with persistence it may be possible to discover exactly what `/cow` was and re-mount it elsewhere.

Comment: thank you some details added. As you saw in the question I've already dived into initrd so I hoped to be able to keep some handle to access it later (by editing inittird scripts).

Comment: @Martian2020 I'm trying to get a working LiveUSB so I can test this... I have a sneaking suspicion that after `pivot_root` it's `/bin/init` (systemd) that unmounts "new_root".  A working theory I'd like to test is to edit the grub boot entry to run `/bin/bash` instead of `/bin/init`... that may give you chance to see what's actually mounted there.

Comment: I've booted with persistence and changes remain on USB (writable/upper), but `mount` does not show USB folders, it is same /cow/upper, so I guess it is under the hood. Mounting another overlay over /usb/writable/upper did not change a thing - the data continued to appear in original folder only, no changes observed in new `upper`

Comment: I meant overlay with `/usb/writable/upper` as lowerdir

Comment: @Martian2020 Yeah the "layers" in an overlayfs are actually file systems not devices.  It's more like a [bind mount](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/198590/what-is-a-bind-mount).  So the game is figuring out what **was** mounted to `/cow`

Comment: As a result of the exercise I want to be able to isolate changes made to the system during install of some packages I want to add to the distro. I want to customize a distro I like w/out building one from scratch. I've tried just merge `/usb/writable/upper` with filesystem.squashfs  but got broken links to libc.so and kernel panic.

Comment: @Martian2020 looks like you can't find this [the way I'd hoped](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679698/where-is-cow-for-linux-booted-from-liveusb/680105?noredirect=1#comment1284825_680105) but, having had time to explore, the LiveUSB created by ubuntu created a non-persistent image with an iso9660 read-only partition.  I wonder if your persistent USB is just adding a writable partition at the end.  Have you tried exploring the USB drive's partition table with `cfdisk`?  If I'm right then there will be writable (ext4?) partition that you can mount.

Comment: there is indeed a partition with upper and work folders on USB. However just merging upper with filesystem.squashfs resulted in broken links for some files, including some libc shared objects and kernel panic when booted. I have not posted this issue as separate question right away because first I thought my USB is corrupt, but then it booted fine with persistence.

Comment: I want to make changes during run and merge them back to liveUSB, and I hoped /cow/upper would help. As of now looks like I'll have to understand what is changed exactly after each action and copy only those.

Comment: USB is made persistent (upper and lower appear) by one boot with `quiet splash` replaced with `persistent`

Comment: @yurenchen wrote a solution. I've discovered it before rearing the answer, wrote an answer based on one of ideas from that with command to edit `casper` script. In case you are interested. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I've discovered this before the answer my @yurenchen, which gives this idea at the end.

Below particular command edits casper script adding bind mount for `shownmounts` boot option. One need to unpack and repack initramfs (`initrd` file for Linux Mint 21) for that. After that `/cow`'s layers are visible in `/casper/cow` after liveUSO system completed boot.

```
# add mount of /cow
sudo sed --in-place --regexp-extended -- 's|(if [[] -n "[$][{]SHOWMOUNTS[}]" []]; then)|\1\n\n        mkdir -p "${rootmnt}/${LIVE_MEDIA_PATH}/cow"\n        mount --bind /cow "${rootmnt}/${LIVE_MEDIA_PATH}/cow"\n|' $work_path/initrd/main/scripts/casper

# change mount option from "move" to "bind".
sudo sed --in-place --regexp-extended -- 's|(mount )-o move( "[$][{]d[}]" "[$][{]rootmnt[}]/[$][{]LIVE_MEDIA_PATH[}]/[$][{]d[#][#][*]/[}]")|\1--bind\2|' $work_path/initrd/main/scripts/casper
```

Also, as a bonus second command changes type of mount as for some reason in booted system in `/casper` I saw folder for squashfs, but it was empty. With with command it was not, but filled with contents. P.S. `/rofs` has same, but for only one upper layer, there could be several squashfs files in the distro's ISO.

Comment: after boot (chroot) I can see `/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs` is here, and it already mount to `/rofs/` well. sorry I didn't understand the situation you descripted. tried on mint 21 livecd.

Comment: @yurenchen. filesystem.squashfs folder is empty in my case for default casper script. Is it not empty on your system?

Comment: yes, It's there,  I'm using `linuxmint-21.1-cinnamon-64bit.iso`, but with [ventoy](https://ventoy.net) tool (in order to try multi distros in one usb, and with persistent, and customize injection to grub.cfg and ramdisk in runtime, it's really powerful)

Comment: @yurenchen, "yes, It's there," indeed it is. But what does it contain? I've just booted LM 21 via Ventoy UEFI, replacing in default menu item with ctrl-e `quiet splash` with `showmounts` and `/cdrom/casper/filesystem.squashfs` is empty. No persistence flag(s) added, just that replacement.