# Is there a way to create a namespace to be able to unmount root folder (to uncover early boot environment)?

Tags: linux, mount, live-usb, namespace

I'm on a quest to access `/cow/upper` when Linux is booted from liveUSB

```
$ mount | grep over
/cow on / type overlay (rw,relatime,lowerdir=filesystem.squashfs,upperdir=/cow/upper,workdir=/cow/work)
```

Recently I've got a new idea to use `unshare --mount`, but on trying after that `# umount /` I get "target busy". Doing it right away was "overoptimistic", I did not think that namespace might be dependent on file structure. Is there a way to make a namespace to be able to unmount root?

P.S. other creative ways to read `/cow/upper`?

Comment: Yes, it's possible.

Comment: @Căcărău, unmount / or read /cow/upper? then how?

Comment: @Martian2020 you don't need to (and cant) unmount /. You need to search for a way to re-mount /cow/upper.  However there's not enough information in your question to tell us what /cow/upper really is.  Someone might be able to figure it out for you if they knew what type of Live USB you were using (what tool created it or where did you download it?)

Comment: @philip, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/679698/where-is-cow-for-linux-booted-from-liveusb I asked that way before I have not received a solution. It is used at least AFAIK in Ubuntu and distro I use more often which is "Ubuntu based" - Linux Mint, latest (20.x) releases.